# jQuery: Select list item, show text

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm curious what the best way to structure a selectable list with accompanied text is.

Instead of writing it all out, I'll show you:
[image]

Or even if you know of a similar example somewhere on the web... just point me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to is sometimes called **tabs** and **panes**. Here's an example from the excellent [jQuery Tools - Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html) library, which you should check out:

```
<!-- the tabs -->
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- tab "panes" -->
<div class="panes">
    <div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div>
    <div>Second tab content</div>
    <div>Third tab content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is as follows

HTML

```
   <ul class="selectable">
        <li>
             This is list 1
             <p class="list-text">text goes here for list 1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
             This is list 2
             <p class="list-text">text goes here for list 2</p>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

This would be the div as showing on the right side

```
   <div id="display-text"></div>
```

CSS

```
   li .list-text { display:none; }
   #display-text {float:right /* whatever styles */}
```

Jquery

```
   $('selectable').click(function(){
       $('#display-text').text($(this).children('.list-text').text());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way. A combination of jQuery, CSS, and HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/BES6h/

This version uses mouse hover instead of click

Answer (score 0):

Check [jQuery UI's tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).